# VScode Terminal issue "bash: cd: too many arguments"

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

When in a VScode terminal session bash based, any command executed is succeeded by a `bash: cd: too many arguments`

I am using a remote ssh shell and it happens on 3 different servers.  If ssh into any of the servers I don't have the same behaviour, direct shell works just fine.

I already tried to create a new connection to the remote server and new workspace.
Searched in logs but did not find any clue about this error.
Searched on stackoverflow for related issues

A bit more context:
I am using a Windows 10 machine
VSCode 1.79
Extensions

```
4ops.terraform
GitLab.gitlab-workflow
hashicorp.hcl
jasonn-porch.gitlab-mr
ms-python.isort
ms-python.python
ms-python.vscode-pylance
ms-toolsai.jupyter
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow
ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit
ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack
ms-vscode.remote-explorer
ms-vscode.remote-server
RolandGreim.sample-ext
```

The Terminal opens direct on my remote Linux box
When running any command, I get the message "bash: cd: too many arguments"
Unfortunately I don't know how to reproduce.
[Examples of behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNW1s.png)

Comment: interestingly, I don't get any results when googling "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues remote "cd: too many arguments"`" or "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues "cd: too many arguments"`". I suggest you also [raise an issue ticket to the VS Code remote extensions' maintainers](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=bug_report.md). If you do, please add a link here to your issue ticket.

Comment: are you using any [prompt commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html) (`echo "$PROMPT_COMMANDS"`) on those remote machines? If so, please show us a [mre]

Comment: Here is the About. Notice I was in the previous version and just updated, but the behavior is the same. 

Version: 1.79.0 (system setup)
Commit: b380da4ef1ee00e224a15c1d4d9793e27c2b6302
Date: 2023-06-07T14:26:35.552Z
Electron: 22.5.5
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

2) No, I don't use spaces on folder name.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try some checks:

- You could check your shell configuration files such as `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.zshrc`, to see if any aliases or functions contain `cd` command.
- Temporarily switch to a different shell such as `zsh` to see if this is a problem with `bash` config.

Comment: on your first bullet, I don't see why that would be the case, since this is happening after _any command_ (did you read the question?)- unless this is a problem with prompt commands, but that's a bit of a nicher shell feature. your second solution is just avoiding the problem- an approach of which I'm not a big fan.

Comment: Let me clarify my intention. With the second bullet, I want to verify if this is a problem with bash shell config or not. I think you accidentally add some aliases or functions (that call `cd` command or pipe the result of a command to `cd`) to bash config. Not avoiding the problem.
With the first bullet, I already read the question and understand it so I suggest you check the configs.

Comment: so... both of your bullet points are suggestions for _troubleshooting_ and not actually _solutions_. Do you understand why I called them out when you call them "solutions"?

Comment: Ok sorry If this word is not correct and misleading you. I will edit it.

Comment: I suggest you also expand on your troubleshooting suggestions _in the answer post_ to explain what exactly the asker should be looking for that could be causing this.

Comment: I added more info to the question

Comment: It seems `precmd` function of your `bash` is modified. Could you run `precmd() {}` in your terminal to check? This command overrides your `precmd` to default.